# How to best make 100k EUR from 20k EUR within in 18 months

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, risk, germany

We will need around 100000 EUR by the end of 2021. We are willing to invest 20000 EUR.
So how would we quintuple our funds within 18 months? We are aware that this is a high-risk undertaking and that we could lose it all. That would be acceptable, it's not a life-or-death situation.

We are based in Germany. We would like this to be handled by a professional, not doing it by ourselves. However, we would like to get some pointers as to which strategy would be suitable for such a risky approach or which insititutions to contact. Is the corona situation an advantage here or not?

Comment: Buy a lottery ticket or play roulette and bet on a colour two or three times for example. That's the sort of risk you need to take and should give you an insight into the most likely outcome i.e. total loss.

Comment: I agree that it comes close to playing a lottery. However, I'm asking for the professional approach.

Comment: If there was one, all professionals (and amateurs too) would be taking it.

Comment: @Sebastian: going to a casino is the approach that has the best chances of working. Everything else is just going to end up with you paying a professional con artist a lot of money to give you much worse chances but the *illusion* that your chances are better.

Comment: If this isn't a life or death situation, why the specific EUR value and timeframe? Perhaps you can adjust your goals to something more reasonable. If you could easily lose 20k and it wouldn't matter, what does the 100k get you? This sounds to me like impatience to meet goals. No reasonable answer is possible because you are asking how best to gamble.

Comment: I made 200K EUR from 40K EUR within 9 months with the trick in (contents screened on public forum). All you need to do is, transfer me the principal to me and wait for 9 months... And hey, this is not a [tag:scams], I have valid and public account here.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in five minutes.

Go to a casino with very high limit. Bet €16,000 on six numbers. If you win, the payout plus the remaining €4,000 is €100,000. If you lose, you bet €2,743 on a single number which gives you €100,005 if you win. If you lose again, you have €1,257 left. Bet €1,103 on two numbers which gives you €20,008 and you start again. If you lose again, €154 leaves you with money for some drinks and a taxi home.

The chance of winning is almost 20% (not quite 20% because the zero on the roulette wheel).

But since you say “we”, that is at least two people, you need to make €2,223 a month each for two months, which should be doable with an extra job, even though it would be hard work. And while getting to €100,000 isn’t guaranteed, you should have no problem ending up with significantly more than €20,000.

Comment: You're spot-on that roulette is as good an investment strategy as any when it comes to this kind of return. But to maximize the odds, isn't it best to put all the bets on a single spin? If you miss your 6-number bet, you have a 1/31 chance of having hit a different single-number bet that round, but if you do it on the next spin, you've only got a 1/37 chance of winning.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry, but 400% return in 18 month is utopic. A return of 4% is a realistic expectation for a regular investment strategy. A return of 40% would be the result of getting lucky with a very speculative investment. But 400%? Forget it.

If duplicating money was that easy, everyone would do it.

The only realistic way to receive such a large return of investment in such a short time would be doing something highly illegal, like drug trafficing or running an elaborate scam scheme. In that case I hope that whatever you need those 100k euro for will also benefit you while you are in prison.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to this is either a small cap stock or options play where you have a clear hypothesis of what that company will do in next 18 months (eg backing a distressed oil company right now expecting oil to rise aggressively in the next 12-18 months and their share price to follow).

The real problem when you want a 'professional' to do this is that people who are good at identifying these types of opportunities are able to spend $20k a week on wine (and then pour the wine away as a joke if they wanted to), so you have basically have no way of hiring one at this price range as its not worth their time (note there are lots of charlatans in this price range in investing, so plenty of snake oil to be bought if you start asking this everywhere).

This leaves you firmly in the world of high risk, uninformed, short term bets, which is firmly the world of gambling as per the other comments. There are a few ways to get this type of 4/1 bet on in gambling - from roulette to finance options to small cap stock to sports betting, but all of them carry large risks to your starting capital. There is no free lunch in this respect - anything you want to do that grows your capital at that rate in that time period carries a large chance of you finishing with zero, and are actually remarkably similar in shape, likely edge and likely outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should hire a scientist who is having time machine and who can travel 18 months ahead and tells you the stocks, which will quintuple. Come back to present time, Invest all the money in those stocks.

Fun apart, 18 months is very short term and very difficult to multiply investment like this. You can consider stock trading investing in a startup company, which is having very low stock price now, which you think it will quintuple in 18 months. It requires concentration of investment. Also, there is very high chance of losing money also.

I would suggest you to go for long term investing to get these kinds of return. Getting rich takes time.

Answer (score 0):

You have 78 weeks in 18 months. Every Monday, use all your cash as collateral to sell OTM options expiring at weeks' end with premiums of at least (assuming zero tax, **2.01%** ROI, but you'll need to figure out how to price in capital gains tax, however that works in Germany). If you are supremely lucky and are never assigned on your options, you should end up with five times your money at 18 months' end, assuming you do this every single week without fail. You can alter this strategy by selling longer-expiry-dated options, but that's up to you.